# Can Hibernate check conflicts (Java)

Tags: java, hibernate

First of all I want you to know I am very new to Hibernate.

I have a MySQL table Account (composite key: account_name & server)
I need to check if there exists the account_name on a given server before inserting it.

Not sure if Hibernate can do the check. If yes, how?

I appreciate your time and reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare the relationship mapping correctly, hibernate will throw an Exception when you try to persist non-existing reference/fk.